# How to get in angular sorted list in backend from response body?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, post, backend

I want to post in request body like this with sort criteria:

```
    {
  "page": {
    "number": 0,
    "size": 10
  },
  "searchSortCriteria": [
    {
      "key": "id",
      "operation": "ASC"
    }
  ]
}
```

Backend gives back already sorted list of expenses from response body like this:

```
{
  "page": null,
  "hasNextPage": false,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "expenses": [
    {
      "createdUser": null,
      "updatedUser": null,
      "createdDate": "2021-07-11T19:50:23",
      "updatedDate": null,
      "id": 4,
      "user": "Radek",
      "amount": 123,
      "currency": "PLN",
      "description": "Grocery",
      "payDate": "2021-07-11",
      "payMethod": {
        "id": 2,
        "payMethodName": "Cash"
      },
      "expenseCategory": {
        "id": 1,
        "categoryName": "Food at home"
      }
    },
    {
      "createdUser": null,
      "updatedUser": null,
      "createdDate": "2021-07-11T19:53:00",
      "updatedDate": null,
      "id": 5,
      "user": "Agata",
      "amount": 52,
      "currency": "PLN",
      "description": "toys",
      "payDate": "2021-07-10",
      "payMethod": {
        "id": 1,
        "payMethodName": "Credit card"
      },
      "expenseCategory": {
        "id": 11,
        "categoryName": "Other"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know how to make proper request but I have a problem how to get the sorted list from response body. I'm looking for any method that can just extract from json in response body.

```
  public findAllPost(criteriaRequest: ExpenseCriteriaRequest): Observable<ExpenseCriteriaRequest> {
    return this.httpClient.post<ExpenseCriteriaRequest>(this.url, criteriaRequest, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.expenseService.findAllPost(this.criteriaRequest)
      .subscribe(request => this.criteriaRequest = request);
  }
```

Comment: The callback function within `subscribe()` is getting the response not the request. It's not clear why you're trying to store the response data as `this.criteriaRequest`. You can use response data as a normal js object like this: `this.expenseService.findAllPost(this.criteriaRequest).subscribe(response => this.expensesList = response.expenses);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this and works

```
  public findAllPost(criteriaRequest: ExpenseCriteriaRequest): Observable<ResponseExpenses> {
    return this.httpClient.post<ResponseExpenses>(this.url, criteriaRequest, this.httpOptions);
  }
```

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.expenseService.findAllPost(this.criteriaRequest)
      .subscribe(response => this.responseExpenses = response);
  }
```